# Turbolinks 5 and history popstate event

Tags: javascript, turbolinks, pushstate, html5-history

I'm using Turbolinks in a Rails 6.1 web app.

I understand that Turbolinks uses AJAX to replace the `body` and uses the `history.pushState()` to update the URL to match.

I've implemented a dialog/modal system that appends an element to the `body` and then shows that element using CSS with some event handlers to close the dialog and remove it when the user clicks a close button on the dialog.

The problem is on mobile device browsers, users prefer to the use back button (bottom-left arrow on Android) instead of reaching up to the top of the dialog and clicking the close button.

So I need a way to intercept the normal Turbolinks `restoration` event and execute some of my own Javascript on the `popstate` event instead of Turbolinks taking over.

I'm aware the Turbolinks docs state that `restoration` events can't be canceled, but I was looking for a way I could use native JS to intercept the `popstate` before Turbolinks ever gets it.

I thought it should be pretty straightforward: when I show a dialog in my Javascript, I execute

```
window
      .history
      .pushState({ dialog: { id: "id-of-dialog" } }, null, window.location)
```

and then have an event handler for the `popstate` that closes the dialog.

```
document.addEventListener("popstate", (event) => {
  console.log(event.state)
  if (event.state.dialog) {
    const dialogId = event.state.dialog.id
    const dialogElement = document.getElementyById(dialogId)

    // Note: I do have some animations for closing, so the closing logic is slightly more
    // complex than this, but this shows the gist of what's going on.
    dialogElement.classList.remove("dialog-container-open")
    dialogElement.remove()

    // Does this stop Turbolinks from taking over?
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
  } else {
    // Do nothing, let Turbolinks handle it
  }
})
```

However, in the `popstate` event, Turbolinks always has a state on top of the history stack and I can't figure out how or where it's happening, thus I can't stop it.

Essentially, I just want to manually manage the history `popstate` logic when the back button is pressed to handle my dialogs. But no matter what, Turbolinks always seems to fire and refresh the page when I just want to close a dialog.

Is there a way to implement this?  I've tried `hashchange` as well, but the `history` API seemed much more promising, since Turbolinks is built on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

The `popstate` event is not cancellable, and cannot be intercepted to prevent the default. (I suppose otherwise developers would be able to prevent users from leaving their sites!).

Turbolinks handles all `popstate` events and has its own mechanisms for doing so. You can push to the history stack in a way that Turbolinks understands by calling:

```
Turbolinks
  .controller
  .pushHistoryWithLocationAndRestorationIdentifier(<YOUR_LOCATION>, Turbolinks.uuid())
```

So rather than thinking that you want to handle the `popstate` event, Turbolinks should now handle that for you, restoring the page as it was before you initialised the dialog. It's worth noting that whilst this is a public method, it's not documented, and therefore maybe removed in future versions.